# Python programming help

Tags: python

I have this python file that I'm working on:

```
class Range:
    """ An object that has a non-negative start position and a non-negative length"""
    def __init__(self, start, end):
                """
                Function: generates a new Range
                Returns : a new range
                Args    : start - start position
                          end - end position
                Start and End must be non-negative """
                self.start = 0
                self.end = 10000
        self.setStart(start)
        self.setEnd(end)
    def getStart(self):
                """
                Function: get the start of the range
                Returns : a number or None
                Args    : start - the int index of the first nucleotide of this range """
        return self.start
    def setStart(self, s):
                """
                Function: set the start of the range
                Returns : None
                Args    : start - a non-negative int or None """
                if type(s) !=int:
                        raise TypeError ("Cannot set Start as this is not an interger")
                elif s < 0:
                        raise ValueError ("Cannot set Start as this is not a non-negative int")
                elif s > self.end:
                        raise ValueError("start cannot be larger than end")
                else:
                        self.start = s
    def getEnd(self):
                """
                Function: get the end of the range
                Returns : a number
                Args    : 
                """
        return self.end
    def setEnd(self, e):
                """
                Function: set the end of the range
                Returns : None
                Args    : end - a non-negative int or None
                """
                if type(e) !=int:
                        raise TypeError ("Cannot set End as this is not an interger")
                elif e < 0:
                        raise ValueError ("Cannot set End as this is not a non-negative int")
                elif e < self.start:
                        raise ValueError ("end has to be larger than start")
                else:
                        self.end = e
    def getLength(self):
                """
                Function: get the length of the range
                Returns : an int. the length of this range
                Args:
                """
                return self.end - self.start
    def overlaps(self, r):
                """
                Function: to test if two nucleotide is overlap
                Returns : True or False
                Args    : other - a Range object
                """
                start1 = self.getStart()
                end1 = start1 + self.getLength()
                start2 = r.getStart()
                end2 = start2 + self.getLength()
                max_start = max(start1,start2)
                min_end = min(end1,end2)
                return min_end - max_start > 0
        if self.getStart() == r.getStart():
                        return True
        else:
            return False

class DNAFeature(Range):
        """Represents a feature on a DNA sequence """
        def __init__(self, seq_name = None, strand = 0, **kwargs):
                """
                Function : represents a rane
                Returns  :
                Args     : strand, seqname, **kwargs
                """         
                Range.__init__(self, **kwargs)
                self.setStrand(strand)
                self.setSeqName(seq_name)
        def getSeqName(self):
                """
                Function: Gets object's Sequence Name
                Returns : seqname - string
                Args    : 
                """
                return self.seq_name
        def setSeqName(self, seq_name):
                """
                Function: Sets object's Sequence Name
                Returns : None
                Args    : seqname - mRNA accession name
                """
        self.seq_name = seq_name
        def getStrand(self):
                """
                Function: Retrieve the strand affiliation of this
                Returns : 1, 0, -1 - strand
                Args    : 
                """
                return self.strand
        def setStrand(self, strand):
                """
                Function: sets which strand the object is on
                Returns : None
                Args    : strand - one of ['+',1,'F','-',-1,'R']
                """
                StrandValues = [1, 0, -1]

        if not strand in StrandValues:
            raise ValueError("only able to setStrand if the values is 1, 0, or -1")
        else:
                        self.strand = strand
        def overlaps(self, other, ignore_strand = True): 
                """
                Function: tests if this overlaps other
                Returns : true if the ranges have same Seqname and overlap, false if not
                Args    : other - another Range object
                """
                if ignore_strand == True and self.getSeqName() == other.getSeqName():
                    return Range.overlaps(self,other)
                else:
                    return False

class GeneModel(DNAFeature):
        def __init__(self, transl_start=None, transl_stop=None, display_id = None, **kwargs):
               """
               Function : contains a group of DNAFeature objects representing exons
               Returns  :
               Args     : **kwargs
               """
               DNAFeature.__init__(self, **kwargs)
               self.setTranslStart(transl_start)
               self.setTranslStop(transl_stop)
               self.setDisplayId(display_id)
               self.exons = [ ]
        def getFeats(self):
                """
                Function: gets object's feats list
                Returns : list of feature keys
                Args    : feature_type - the type of strand the object holds
                """
                self.exons.sort(cmp=self.start)
                return self.exons
        def addFeat(self, feat):
                """
                Function: adds SeqFeature to feats keys
                Returns : None
                Args    : feat - a single SeqFeature object
                """
                if type(feat) == DNAFeature:
                        self.exons.append(feat)
                else:
                        raise TypeError("Cannot add feature as it is not a type of DNAFeature")
        def setTranslStart(self, transl_start):
               """
               Function : accepts an non-negative int, sets the start position of the initiating ATG
               Returns  :
               Args     : transl_start
               """
               if transl_start == None:
                   self.transl_start = None
                   return
               elif type(transl_start) !=int:
                   raise TypeError("TranslStart cannot be set since it is not a type of int")
               elif transl_start < 0:
                   raise ValueError("TranslStart cannot be set to a negative int")
               else:
                   self.translStart = transl_start
        def getTranslStart(self):
                """
                Function: the start position of initiating ATG codon
                Return  : an int.
                Args    :
                """
                return self.transl_start
        def setTranslStop(self, transl_stop):
                """
                Function: set the end position of initiating ATG codon
                Return : None
                Args   : a positive int
                """
                if transl_stop == None:
                   self.transl_stop = None
                   return
                elif type(transl_stop) !=int:
                   raise TypeError("TranslStop cannot be set since it is not a type of int")
                elif transl_stop < 0:
                   raise ValueError("TranslStop cannot be set to a negative int")
                else:
                   self.translStop = transl_stop
        def getTranslStop(self):
                """
                Function: the end position of initiating ATG codon
                Return  : an int.
                Args    :
                """
                return self.transl_stop
        def setDisplayId(self, display_id):
                """
                Function: set the display id
                Returns : None
                Args    : display_id - a string, a preferred name for this
                """
                if type(display_id) !=str:
                        raise TypeError("Cannot set displayId as it is not a type string")
                else:
                        self.display_id = display_id
        def getDisplayId(self):
                """
                Function: get the display id
                Returns : display_id - a string, a preferred name for this, e.g AT1G10555.1
                Args    : 
                """
                return self.display_id
```

Then, I got some code from my professor to test my file:

```
class TestGeneModelConstructor(unittest.TestCase):
    def testGeneModelConstructor(self):
        """GeneModel constructor supports named arguments display_id,transl_start,transl_stop"""
        p1.GeneModel(start=0,end=10,seq_name='something',strand=1,display_id='foobar',
                     transl_start=0,transl_stop=10)

    def testGeneModelConstructorDefaults(self):
        """Default values for display_id, transl_start, transl_stop should be None"""
        r = p1.GeneModel()
        self.assertEquals(r.getDisplayId(),None)
        self.assertEquals(r.getTranslStart(),None)
        self.assertEquals(r.getTranslStop(),None)

    def testGeneModelConstructorWrongTypeDisplayId(self):
        """Raise a TypeError if display_id is not a string."""
        self.assertRaises(TypeError,p1.GeneModel,display_id=0)

    def testGeneModelConstructorWrongTypeTranslStart(self):
        """Raise a TypeError if transl_start is not an int."""
        self.assertRaises(TypeError,p1.GeneModel,transl_start='0')

    def testGeneModelConstructorWrongTypeTranslStop(self):
        """Raise a TypeError if transl_stop is not an int."""
        self.assertRaises(TypeError,p1.GeneModel,transl_stop='0')

    def testGeneModelConstructorWrongValueTranslStart(self):
        """Raise a ValueError if transl_start is int < 0."""
        self.assertRaises(ValueError,p1.GeneModel,transl_start=-1)

    def testGeneModelConstructorWrongValueTranslStop(self):
        """Raise a ValueError if transl_stop is int < 0."""
        self.assertRaises(ValueError,p1.GeneModel,transl_stop=-1)
```

I have run it and got these errors:

```
ERROR: Default values for display_id, transl_start, transl_stop should be None
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/trungpham/binf_prog/class/test/testProject1.py", line 117, in testGeneModelConstructorDefaults
    r = p1.GeneModel()
TypeError: __init__() takes at least 3 arguments (1 given)

======================================================================
ERROR: Raise a ValueError if transl_start is int < 0.
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/trungpham/binf_prog/class/test/testProject1.py", line 136, in testGeneModelConstructorWrongValueTranslStart
    self.assertRaises(ValueError,p1.GeneModel,transl_start=-1)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/unittest.py", line 336, in failUnlessRaises
TypeError: __init__() takes at least 3 non-keyword arguments (2 given)

======================================================================
ERROR: Raise a ValueError if transl_stop is int < 0.
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/trungpham/binf_prog/class/test/testProject1.py", line 140, in testGeneModelConstructorWrongValueTranslStop
    self.assertRaises(ValueError,p1.GeneModel,transl_stop=-1)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/unittest.py", line 336, in failUnlessRaises
TypeError: __init__() takes at least 3 non-keyword arguments (1 given)
```

I'm not sure what is wrong, I have tried to fixed it couple times, but haven't figure out what is wrong in my codes.

Alright, I have change my code in DNAFeature like this:

```
class DNAFeature(Range):
    """Represents a feature on a DNA sequence """
    def __init__(self, seq_name = None, strand = 0, **kwargs):
            """
            Function : represents a rane
            Returns  :
            Args     : strand, seqname, **kwargs
            """         
            Range.__init__(self, 0,10000, **kwargs)
            self.setStrand(strand)
            self.setSeqName(seq_name)
```

And then, get 3 more errors and 1 failure like this:

```
ERROR: DNAFeature on different sequence don't overlap
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  Traceback (most recent call last):
     File "/Users/trungpham/binf_prog/class/test/testProject1.py", line 164, in testDiffSequenceOverlaps
    r1 = p1.DNAFeature(start=0,end=10,strand=1,seq_name="foo")
     File "/Users/trungpham/binf_prog/tpham22/project1/p1.py", line 95, in __init__
    Range.__init__(self, 0, 10000, **kwargs)
TypeError: __init__() got multiple values for keyword argument 'start'

======================================================================
 ERROR: DNAFeatures on the same strand can overlap if ignore_strand is True.
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  Traceback (most recent call last):
     File "/Users/trungpham/binf_prog/class/test/testProject1.py", line 185, in testDiffStrandsDontOverlap
    r1 = p1.DNAFeature(start=0,end=10,strand=1,seq_name="foo")
     File "/Users/trungpham/binf_prog/tpham22/project1/p1.py", line 95, in __init__
    Range.__init__(self, 0, 10000, **kwargs)
TypeError: __init__() got multiple values for keyword argument 'start'

======================================================================
ERROR: GeneModel constructor supports named arguments display_id,transl_start,transl_stop
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/Users/trungpham/binf_prog/class/test/testProject1.py", line 113, in testGeneModelConstructor
    transl_start=0,transl_stop=10)
     File "/Users/trungpham/binf_prog/tpham22/project1/p1.py", line 151, in __init__
    DNAFeature.__init__(self, **kwargs)
      File "/Users/trungpham/binf_prog/tpham22/project1/p1.py", line 95, in __init__
    Range.__init__(self, 0, 10000, **kwargs)
TypeError: __init__() got multiple values for keyword argument 'start'

FAIL: Raise a TypeError if seq_name is not a string.
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/trungpham/binf_prog/class/test/testProject1.py", line 98, in testDNAFeatureSeqNameConstructorWrongType
    self.assertRaises(TypeError,p1.DNAFeature,seq_name=0)
AssertionError: TypeError not raised
```

Comment: Please write a better title next time.  Asking for "help!!!" doesn't make people want to help.

Comment: Read the [Default Argument Values](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/controlflow.html#default-argument-values) section from the Python tutorial. [Dive Into Python](http://diveintopython.org/power_of_introspection/optional_arguments.html) has something about this, too.

Comment: sorry, was a bit emergency so I just put in help x< will be more specify next time.

Comment: Are you sure that the DNAFeature constructor was the *only* thing you changed? The new error message you just showed should only be possible if you also changed something *else* somewhere. Are there any other references you have to `start` or `end`?

Comment: @roger: there is a difference between discouraging and enforcing.

Comment: @Silent: I've had more than 10 people comment to thank me (and how many more didn't comment?), just within the past day, because they had no idea there was even a problem with the tag.  This is why I link to the discussion on meta every time — and it also has guidelines for how to improve poor questions, which are much more likely to be tagged "homework" than other "basic/pedagogical" questions.  Will I be watching this tag forever? No, but for a short while I can discourage it.

Comment: @roger: exactly! there isn't a problem with the tag. you just choose to play a role of a righteous enforces. And what is your improvement to this "wall-of-code" question except fixing basic grammar?

Comment: @Silent: The last block wasn't marked as code, causing the underscores to be interpreted as bold (you can see this in the diff) and other Markdown problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several things wrong:

**Firstly:**

In your test function, testGeneModelConstructorDefaults, you have the comment: "Default values for display_id, transl_start, transl_stop should be None".

The problem you are seeing is that you have only set up the defaults on 1 of the 3 arguments; whereas this test function assumes you have set up defaults on all three. To fix this, you need to define the constructor like this:

```
def __init__(self, transl_start=None, transl_stop=None, display_id = None, **kwargs)
```

By having the keyword arguments, it will use the default of `None`. If you don't specify those keyword arguments explicitly, Python will complain (as it is currently doing).

**Secondly:**

You have to consider your superclass constructors. The `Range` superclass asks for two parameters: start and end.

```
def __init__(self, start, end):
```

However, when the `DNAFeature` constructor calls the `Range` superclass, it doesn't pass in begin or end:

```
Range.__init__(self, **kwargs)
```

*This* is where I think the error is now (I think before it was at the `p1.GeneModel()` call - there are probably different error lines in your two error messages).

To fix this, make the values for start and end into keyword parameters also. So instead of:

```
def __init__(self, start, end):
```

make it:

```
def __init__(self, start=0, end=10000):
```

You can then delete the following lines of code in your `range` constructor:

```
self.start = 0
self.end = 10000
```

That should at least get you past this error - you may find more errors that you have.

Comment: I have tried this too but still get the same error, dont know why

Comment: Make sure you are running the correct version of the code. In my experience, some IDEs (such as Pythonwin) don't recompile the pyc files, causing it to run an old version of the code. Try restarting your editor and trying again. In any case, you will definitely need the =None part if you want to allow default values (as per your test cases).

Comment: Or he needs to reload() the module.

Comment: Yeah, exactly same error, and I have tried to fixed it like for hours...dont know why its still pop up that error

Comment: @pmt0512 - I found what is causing your error. The first error (which we fixed with that change) was in the constructor of `GeneModel`. However, there is a **second** error in the calling of the constructor of `Range`; and we were confused because it caused *almost exactly* the same error message (but not quite). See my edited response for how to fix it (in the **Secondly** section)

Comment: oh, I see, yea, I regconized that error too, but in my Range class, i have define my self.start = 0 and self.end = 10000... so can I input these 2 value into Range.__init_(self, 0, 10000, **kwargs), will this work?? Thanks Smashery

Comment: @pmt0512 - Yep, that's exactly right. So you don't actually assign `self.start` and `self.end` in your DNAFeature class - you do it by calling that `Range` constructor *exactly* like you just wrote it then, and it should work.

Comment: I tried Range.__init__(self, 0, 10000, **kwargs), or even self, 1, 2, **kwargs, they all give me 3 more errors and 1 failure

Comment: After fixing that, you'll probably get another error. You need to handle the case where display_id is not given a value (as your `setDisplayId` method assumes it will be a string). Once you've fixed that, all seems to work fine.

Comment: @pmt0512 - What are the errors this time, though? They should be different. You can edit your original question to provide more information.

Comment: it didnt give me display_id error but instead the DNAclass error and 1 failure, let me put them in my header

Comment: Thanks. It seems we're making progress. Are you sure you didn't change anything else? If I make the same changes you did, I do not see those errors.

Comment: yah, I just put 0, 10000 in, and get those error =/ dont know why

Comment: @pmt0512 - Sorry, I made a mistake; I missed reading a line of code up top. I have updated my answer, and I'm almost certain this should fix it now. You will need to undo those changes I suggested last time, so that your DNAFeature constructor only says: `Range.__init__(self, **kwargs)`. Let me know how that goes :-)

Comment: Seems like it fix the error of default values, but then I'm having like 26 errors now @.@ wow....

Comment: Mostly are those AttributeError: Range instance has no attribute 'end' ; AttributeError: GeneModel instance has no attribute 'end'
; AttributeError: DNAFeature instance has no attribute 'end'

as DNAFeature and GeneModel are subclass of Range, and they all have the start and end, so when I delete the self.start and self.end in Range, it raise those Errors... :-/

Comment: But aren't you calling the `self.setStart(start)` and `self.setEnd(end)` functions? Surely they set `self.start` and `self.end`?

Comment: Yeah, I dont know what's wrong but it keep saying those errors that Range, DNAFeature, and GeneModel has no instance 'end', no idea whats wrong here, well, can you take a look at my other errors with transl_start and trans_stop please, not sure what I'm doing wrong there too =/

Comment: It would be very helpful if you could clean up your question, so it's clear which ones are still errors, and which ones are fixed. Could you perhaps rewrite your question and show us all of your code, and some or all of the error messages.

Comment: Also, please be careful to format it correctly. Because Python is so dependent on whitespace, if you get this wrong, it will be much more difficult for us to help you.

Comment: @pmt0512 - Looking at it again, I made another mistake. Seems you might need those lines of code after all.

Comment: I'll try working on it for tomorrow as its 2AM here, have early school tomorrow, so thanks Smashery, I will post whats wrong coming up with my codes tomorrow.. :) thanks again, really appreciate your help

Comment: Hey, I just figure out the errors, your codes was right but the testing code in other part raise the other errors, so I just fix them all already, thanks Smashery ^^

Answer (score 1):

It appears that the tests are assuming that all parameters are passed by value.  You need to give the positional arguments defaults.

Comment: That is not a problem. Positional args can be specified by name, but all other args following that must also be.

Comment: You are right, I forgot that all parameters can be called positionally.  I don't use named parameters a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Smashery is right. Try running this simplified code:

```
class GeneModel(object):
    def __init__(self, transl_start=None, transl_stop=None, display_id = None, **kwargs):
        pass

def testGeneModelConstructor():
    g = GeneModel(start=0,end=10,seq_name='something',strand=1,display_id='foobar', transl_start=0,transl_stop=10)

def testGeneModelConstructorDefaults():
    r = GeneModel()

testGeneModelConstructor()
testGeneModelConstructorDefaults()
```

Comment: Actually, I cannot fix or change the testing code, I only can change my codes, then use the default testing code to grade my file >.<, and I have tried input None values in for translt_start, transl_stop, and display_id too, but still having the same error =/

Comment: @pmt0512 - I don't think Hollister is telling you to replace your code. He's just telling you to try running this, and see if it works. If it works, then that's good. If not, then something is seriously wrong.

Comment: So, you mean use this code to test my file? or using my prof's testing code to test Hollister's code, sorry I'm quite confused here >.<

Comment: @pmt0512 - We were just suggesting that, completely independently of your code, run this code and see what happens. However, I believe I've found a **second** error in your code, which should get you past that error. Check my response.